# git: 'send-email' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, git-send-email

I'm trying to send patches with the `git send-email` But I get the following error:

```
git: 'send-email' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

How to make `git send-email` works ?

Related links:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-send-email.html

Comment: Which version of git are you using? do you have the right 'minus' sign (if you have any internationalization)

Comment: How did you install git? What OS are you using (and if Linux what distribution)?

Comment: try `git-send-email` and see if that is found.

Comment: See also: full setup info (my own Q&A): [How to configure and use `git send-email` to work with gmail to email patches to developers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68238913/4561887)

Comment: In my case, I installed `git-email` but it didn't work because I have a `nix-env` `git` installed which has precedence over the system `git` in my `$PATH`. Removing the `nix-env` version solved the issue.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You need to install the `git-email` package for it to work.

On `Ubuntu`, the usual `apt-get install git-email` works fine. I can confirm the same for `Fedora` as well (`yum install git-email`).

[cebewee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647987/cebewee) mentions the rationale in the comments:

> Linux distributions often like to split up packages to avoid
>   dependencies needed only by optional functionality (like send-email).

Note that you have to [configure](http://blog.bisect.de/2012/01/how-to-send-patches-via-git-send-email.html) it before starting.

Comment: Interesting to know that as one who has msysgit-for-windows where it is all in the one package.

Comment: Linux distributions often like to split up packages to avoid dependencies needed only by optional functionality (like send-email).